# How may I avoid a syntax error when echoing JSON.parse in a script in PHP foreach?

Tags: php, json, foreach, syntax-error, echo

This is my first question on StackOverflow, and I consider myself a novice (self-taught). Please bear with me.

The following script works on the page when not wrapped in php tags.

```
<script>
  var json = '{"submitted_values":{"15":{"15.1":"123"}}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

function printValues(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
      printValues(obj[k]);
    } else {
      document.write(obj[k]);
    };
  }
};
document.write(obj["submitted_values"]["15"]["15.1"]);
</script>
```

The same script doesn't work on the page when wrapped in php tags and being echoed.

It actually crashes the website.

The second line `var json = '{"submitted_values":{"15":{"15.1":"123"}}}';` in the next block of code results in `syntax error, unexpected ':'`.

```
<?php echo '<script>
  var json = '{"submitted_values":{"15":{"15.1":"123"}}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

function printValues(obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
      printValues(obj[k]);
    } else {
      document.write(obj[k]);
    };
  }
};
document.write(obj["submitted_values"]["15"]["15.1"]);
</script>'; ?>
```

The following describes what I want to get working.

The test is one table-row with three columns.

Col 1 in the next block of code is the script from above and, of course, doesn't work.

Col 2 works and results in a string where `document.write(obj["submitted_values"]["15"]["15.1"]);` in the script works. I've tested an actual (elaborate, nested) string, and it does work but only when outside php tags.

Col 3 is the script from above but with `'{"submitted_values":{"15":{"15.1":"123"}}}'` replaced with `' . esc_html($incomplete_submission->submission) . '`.

Col 3 is what I ultimately want to work in the WordPress plugin.

If it can be done, will someone kindly copy from `echo '<!-- Col 3 --><td><script>` down in the following block of code, change the code so it will work, and paste it all in an answer?

I ask for the whole thing to be pasted because it may save you additional back and forth.

Thanks!

```
<?php
foreach ($incomplete_submissions as $incomplete_submission)
{
 echo '<!-- Row --><tr>';
 echo '<!-- Col 1 --><td><script>
    var json = '{"submitted_values":{"15":{"15.1":"123"}}}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

function printValues(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
            printValues(obj[k]);
        } else {
            document.write(obj[k]);
        };
    }
};
document.write(obj["submitted_values"]["15"]["15.1"]);
</script></td>';
    echo '<!-- Col 2 --><td>' . esc_html($incomplete_submission->submission) . '</td>';
    echo '<!-- Col 3 --><td><script>
    var json = ' . esc_html($incomplete_submission->submission) . ';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

function printValues(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
            printValues(obj[k]);
        } else {
            document.write(obj[k]);
        };
    }
};
document.write(obj["submitted_values"]["15"]["15.1"]);
</script></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: You have an unescaped quote `'` there. Fix that

Comment: Don’t output large chunks of mostly static HTML / JS code using echo to begin with. Use the syntax shown under https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php, and only use small PP code sections to output the parts that are actually dynamic.

Comment: _“It actually crashes the website.”_ - meaning what - “blank page”? Then you should go enable proper PHP error reporting via the PHP configuration first of all, so that PHP has a chance to tell you about syntax errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Here's how it's done:

```
echo '<!-- Col 3 --><td>';
?>
<script>
var json = '<?php echo $incomplete_submission->submission; ?>';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

function printValues(obj) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
            printValues(obj[k]);
        } else {
            document.write(obj[k]);
        };
    }
};
document.write(obj["submitted_values"]["15"]["15.1"]); </script>
<?php
echo '</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has Heredoc and Nowdoc strings, which are the best way to handle multiline strings in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

You can solve your problem by using this type of string as below:

```
<?php echo <<<EOD
    <script>
        var json = '{"submitted_values":{"15":{"15.1":"123"}}}';
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);

        function printValues(obj) {
          for (var k in obj) {
            if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
              printValues(obj[k]);
            } else {
              document.write(obj[k]);
            };
          }
        };
        printValues(obj);
    </script>
EOD; 
?>
```

Beware that the end token EOD must not be indented at all, or PHP won't acknowledge it. Also, you don't have to use "EOD"; it can be any string you want.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When that code is working correctly, it will echo 123. In PHP 7.3+, the whole script is echoed. It will crash the site. Try your code yourself: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: @tom-usher
When you testing the code in http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com the result is equal to "html output of the code". If you test the code on your host , when you try to open the page in the browser you can see that is working correctly...
vote up please. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @cbroe 's comment, you can use the below code after setting the $myJson variable with your own, and use it in wordpress plugin to solve the problem:

```
<script>
    function printValues(jsonString) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        for (var k in obj) {
            if (obj[k] instanceof Object) {
                printValues(obj[k]);
            } else {
                document.write(obj[k]);
            };
        }
    };
</script>
<?php
    $myJson = '{"submitted_values":{"15":{"15.1":"123"}}}';
    foreach ($incomplete_submissions as $incomplete_submission)
    {
        ?>
        <tr><!-- Row -->
            <td><!-- Col 1 -->
                <script>
                    var jsonString = <?php echo $myJson; ?>;
                    printValues(jsonString);
                </script>
            </td>
            <td><!-- Col 2 -->
                <?php echo esc_html($incomplete_submission->submission); ?>
            </td>
            <td><!-- Col 3 -->
                <script>
                    var jsonString = <?php echo wp_json_encode($incomplete_submission->submission); ?>;
                    printValues(jsonString);
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your code results in columns 1 and 3 being empty. ```document.write(obj["submitted_values"]["15"]["15.1"]);```is the part of my script that returns the value of 15.1, which is 123.